# Nginx SSL Certificate error:0200100D Permission denied

Tags: nginx

To summarize, I am running the latest version of LibreTime on a Digitalocean droplet.
Ubuntu 20.04.

My setup is running smoothly for the most part. However I am experiencing a problem where after about 2-4 hours of up time I get a continuous error from LiquidSoap, which causes CPU and memory to max out. This is the error:

```
[harbor:2] Failed to accept new client: SSL: Certificate error: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
```

Upon research it seems to related to the fact the Nginx can not access the certificate due to incorrect permissions. I have tried:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /etc/letsencrypt/
chmod -R 755 /etc/letsencrypt/
```

```
restorecon /etc/nginx/ssl/*
restorecon -vF /etc/ssl/certs/ssl.bundle.crt
```

This is the result of running `sudo ps aux | grep nginx`:

```
root         914  0.0  0.0  61588  1656 ?        Ss   16:40   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data     915  0.0  0.4  62440  8436 ?        S    16:40   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data     916  0.0  0.4  62636  9004 ?        S    16:40   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        5479  0.0  0.1   5192  2484 pts/0    S+   17:11   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

What is confusing me is that the everything runs fine for 2-4 hours when I restart Nginx, and then the error occurs, how can it be possible to it accesses the cert for a while and then suddenly doesn't have access.

Thanks for any ideas.